# Codeigniter app INSIDE Laravel website under Nginx - how to route it correctly?

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, laravel-4, routes

I'm using the [JBimages](http://justboil.me/) uploader plugin for TinyMCE in my Laravel 4.2 website; the webserver is Nginx, so I cannot use the .htaccess files provided with CodeIgniter.

My problem is that I cannot access the plugin controllers, beacuse I get a Laravel HttpNotFoundException. The plugin is trying to access this url:

`app/assets/backend/plugins/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php/upload/english`,

but looks like it gets intercepted by this Laravel route:

```
Route::any('{section}/{slug}', ['as' =>....);
```

I tried using a where() condition on the route:

```
->where('section', '^(?!app).*$');
```

but to no avail.
Curiously when I access the CI installation at `app/assets/backend/plugins/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/ci/` it seems the framework is called correctly. This are the CodeIgniter's configs:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

I tried changing the uri_protocol to REQUEST_URI, removing the 'index.php' and setting the base_url to the plugin path but nothing seems to be working.

This is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  dev.mywebsite.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.access.log  main;
    root   /var/www/html/mywebsite;
    location / {
        root   /var/www/html/mywebsite;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location ~ server.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ filters.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ index.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I can't tell if it's a Nginx problem or laravel's or CodeIgniter's. Google hasn't provided any relevant solution so far.

Comment: Try pointing the route to a laravel controller which includes the CI path index.php. if the request uri remains unchanged by laravel then ci should be able to break it down and point to the proper controller